# Use Solaris IPF to redirect cerain IPs from port 80 to port 8080

Tags: firewall, solaris

Anyone slick enough with Solaris 10 firewalls to reproduce the follow iptables rule for ipf?

```
-A PREROUTING  -p tcp -m tcp !--src-range 192.168.1.100-192.168.1.200 -dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 8080
```

Basically I want to take all traffic going to port 80 on an IP and redirect it to port 8080 (and ideally I'd like to do this only for source IPs that aren't in a certain range)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the `ipf.conf` man page:

> ..there is currently not a way [..] to match ranges of IP addresses that do not express themselves easily as bitmasks.

You can get it to work using multiple rules, although it's not pretty. The following rules in `ipnat.conf` should meet your requirements (assuming `e1000g0` is your network interface, and assuming I've done the subnet mask calculations correctly):

```
rdr e1000g0 ! from 192.168.1.0/24 to any port = 80 -> 127.0.0.1 port 8080 tcp
rdr e1000g0 from 192.168.1.0/26   to any port = 80 -> 127.0.0.1 port 8080 tcp
rdr e1000g0 from 192.168.1.64/27  to any port = 80 -> 127.0.0.1 port 8080 tcp
rdr e1000g0 from 192.168.1.96/30  to any port = 80 -> 127.0.0.1 port 8080 tcp
rdr e1000g0 from 192.168.1.201/32 to any port = 80 -> 127.0.0.1 port 8080 tcp
rdr e1000g0 from 192.168.1.202/31 to any port = 80 -> 127.0.0.1 port 8080 tcp
rdr e1000g0 from 192.168.1.204/30 to any port = 80 -> 127.0.0.1 port 8080 tcp
rdr e1000g0 from 192.168.1.208/28 to any port = 80 -> 127.0.0.1 port 8080 tcp
rdr e1000g0 from 192.168.1.224/27 to any port = 80 -> 127.0.0.1 port 8080 tcp
```